# angular nativescript modal is behind the tabview in ios

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am using tabview and in any one the tab using modal positioning at the bottom of the page. but my bottom of the layout hides behind the tabview in ios. can anyone suggest an idea to overcome this?  I have attached the screenshot of my page [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x5Mk.png)
I am expecting the page like this,[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkpOj.png)  I have attached my code,

> my-events.component.html

```
<GridLayout class="a-m-t-25">
  <StackLayout>
    <GridLayout row="*">
      <ListView class="cv-list" [items]="data" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)">
        <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index">
          <FlexboxLayout class="cv-list-item" alignItems="center">
            <StackLayout class="list-item-c">
              <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column">
                <Label class="list-item-heading" [text]='item.name'></Label>
              </FlexboxLayout>
            </StackLayout>
          </FlexboxLayout>
        </ng-template>
      </ListView>
    </GridLayout>
  </StackLayout>
  <ns-modal *ngIf="showModal" [position]="'bottom'" (close)="showModal = false">
    <ns-event-attendance></ns-event-attendance>
  </ns-modal>
</GridLayout>
```

> my-events.component.ts

```
onItemTap(args) {
  this.showModal = true;
  console.log(args.index);
}
```

> modal.component.html

```
<GridLayout>
  <StackLayout (tap)="closeModal()" class="transparent-background"></StackLayout>
  <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column" justifyContent="flex-end" >
    <StackLayout class="modal-container" (tap)="closeModal()"  >
      <FlexboxLayout  justifyContent="center" padding="20">
        <StackLayout  width="45" borderRadius="10" height="4" backgroundColor="#a9a9a9"></StackLayout>
      </FlexboxLayout>
      <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout borderColor="#DFE1E6" borderBottomWidth="1" padding="20">
          <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column">
            <Label class="text-heading" text="Lake clean up"></Label>
            <Label class="list-item-sub" text="Tower park, Anna Nagar"></Label>
            <Label class="list-item-last" text="Thursday, November 5, 3:00 PM"></Label>
          </FlexboxLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout borderColor="#DFE1E6" borderBottomWidth="1" padding="20">
          <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column">
            <Label class="text-normal" text="Role"></Label>
            <Label class="text-dull" text="Section Leader"></Label>
          </FlexboxLayout>
        </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
  </FlexboxLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

> modal.component.ts

```
closeModal() {
  console.log('coming in '); 
  this.close.emit(true);
}
```

Comment: I guess your modal is placed inside TabView, try moving it outside TabView.

Comment: @Manoj If I place it outside TabView, then it is opening as a new Page which will hide the ListView behind it.

Comment: It should not be a new page until you have routing setup. Do you have a Playground setup?

Comment: No, we not have a playground setup

Comment: Are the model component correctly declared? example  declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ModalComponent
    ]

Comment: ya. The issue is solved by placing the modal component outside the tabview and manage it through observable.